# How can I create a dummy variable based on text analysis and time sequence of events?

Tags: r, date, dummy-variable

| Coworkers | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2011-01-01 |
| D | 2011-01-02 |
| B;;D | 2011-01-03 |
| E;;F | 2011-01-04 |
| D | 2012-11-05 |
| D;;G | 2012-11-06 |
| A | 2012-11-09 |

Hello, I am trying to create a dummy variable based on text analysis (e.g., `grepl`).
The unit of analysis is a project, and the two main variables are coworkers (text) and date.

I am curious if there is any way that I can create a dummy variable that indicates all projects done by a worker who collaborated with "B" (in this example, D) as 1.
One more KEY condition I would like to add is...  I would like to give the value of 1 only to projects that occurred AFTER B and D worked together.
I mean, in this case, I want to mark the project in the second row, which is done by D, as 0 because it occurred before B and D met.

Can I create this type of variable using R commands?
As I have millions of observations, I would not be able to do it manually.
Alphabets in the table are texts.

Thank you!

PS. In the "Coworkers" column, coworkers are separated by ;;

Comment: With your condition of *"after B and D worked together"*, then **none** of your data matches: `B` never reappears.

Comment: How is this "natural language processing"? The [tag:nlp] tag seems extraneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution with `tidyverse` (at least I think this is what you are looking for). First, I create a new column (i.e., `flag`) that indicates whether `B` has co-worked with `D`, and if so, then I assign a 1. Next, I use `cummax` which will everything 1 after the first row of `B;;D`. This creates two groups for the before and after. Next, I use `case_when` to change the first occurrence to 0, as you specified. Then, for any row with `D`, I change to 1 and all others are changed to 0.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse(str_detect(Coworkers, "B;;D") | str_detect(Coworkers, "D;;B"), 1, 0),
         flag = cummax(flag == 1),
         flag = case_when(flag != 0 & !duplicated(flag) ~ 0,
                          grepl("D", Coworkers) & flag == 1 ~ 1,
                          TRUE ~ 0))
```

**Output**

```
  Coworkers       Date flag
1         A 2011-01-01    0
2         D 2011-01-02    0
3      B;;D 2011-01-03    0
4      E;;F 2011-01-04    0
5         D 2012-11-05    1
6      D;;G 2012-11-06    1
7         A 2012-11-09    0
8         B 2012-12-09    0
9      C;;B 2012-12-09    0
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(Coworkers = c("A", "D", "B;;D", "E;;F", "D", "D;;G", 
"A", "B", "C;;B"), Date = c("2011-01-01", "2011-01-02", "2011-01-03", 
"2011-01-04", "2012-11-05", "2012-11-06", "2012-11-09", "2012-12-09", 
"2012-12-09")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Your `flag` variable is not what has been asked. I think the column is supposed to have `1` corresponding to only `D` and `D::G` which appeared after `B;;D`

Comment: @slowowl That would be clearer with an expected output. But I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @AndrewGillreath-Brown Thank you so much! This resolved my first research question! I have an additional question, can I visit with the next related question!

Comment: @JunoOh You're welcome! Yes, if you create a new question, then you can comment and link it here and I can look at it.